# I m trying to deploy my fastapi project with deta but give the following error

Tags: python, fastapi

After runing this command

deta auth disable

it gave me the following error
Error: no deta micro initialized in '/media/israr/9852c72c-b7ae-4c4a-997b-2b1eae4d2a3d/GitHub/Socialapp'

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no deta microserver initialized in the folder you want to deploy.

You can create a new deta server with `deta new`

https://docs.deta.sh/docs/cli/commands#deta-new